# How to filter list of dicts to leave only unique dicts

Tags: python

I have query created using SQLAlchemy. This query generator return 4 objects that have list of rules. Each rule is dict like: `{'type': u'psome_type', 'options': {}, 'weight': 1.0}`. I want to get one iterable element that will contains only unique dict. 
I try to use set():

```
rule_sets = DBSession.query(ProductSortRuleSet).all()
    rules = set()
    for i in rule_sets:
        for j in i.rules:
            rules.update(j)
```

But when we pass to set.update dictionary, it update only by key, but i want to update by all dictionary.

How can i do this?

Comment: Try to convert dicts to tuples of tuples sorted by keys. Then you add them to the set and will get unique results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop adds all the keys of the different dictionaries to a `set`. If, instead, you do `rules.update(d.items())` you would get a `set` of all the items, and could re-create one `dict` with all the entries from it (assuming no duplicate keys with different values), but that seems not to be what you want.

```
>>> lst = [{"foo": 42, "bar": 23}, {"foo": 3.14}, {"bar": 23, "foo": 42}]
>>> s = set()
>>> for d in lst:
...     s.update(d.items())
...     
>>> dict(s)
{'foo': 3.14, 'bar': 23}
```

Note how the `"foo": 42` entry disappeared. Instead, you can create hashable `frozenset` from the dictionaries' items, collect those in a `set`, and create new unique dictionaries from those:

```
>>> lst = [{"foo": 42, "bar": 23}, {"foo": 3.14}, {"bar": 23, "foo": 42}]
>>> [dict(x) for x in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in lst)]
[{'foo': 3.14}, {'foo': 42, 'bar': 23}]
```

Comment: Thanks, its help me very much, for my reason first i must join all my lists to one, and after that convert it to frozenset

Comment: @VladyslavUshakov Noticed that you very briefly accepted and then unaccepted this answer. Was this a mistake, or is there anything wrong that I can still help you with? (Of course, whether you accept the answer or not is entirely up to you, just being curious.)